# Why is LSCopyItemInfoForURL deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to find the reason why LSCopyItemInfoForURL is depreciated. I tried to read the apple developer page but i couldn't find the reason. I am new to mac. Can any expert give the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Ask this question on Apple Developper forum. Only there you can find some who has an answer. But I am not sure Apple talks about deprecation. It’s their choice. Usually, that means that there is a new way to do the same thing and it has been considered that the new way should be ´The Way ´